# how does wordpress know what page to open

Tags: wordpress

Newbie to WordPress coming from Joomla. Trying to get my head around how wp knows to use base.php or page.php. also if I have a page called about us do I create a page called page-about-us.php  and if so how does wp know to open it

Comment: That will be a good start : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

### Slug

Slug is a simple id of **posts** and **pages**. WordPress by default creates slug for **Posts**, **Pages**, **Categories** and **Tags** as long as we have not created a specific Slug. Slugs are always created in small letters with “-” sign in between the words.

### Example

```
your page name is -> “about us“  the slug of that page will be “about-us”.
```

In this way,this will execute from `page.php` and if you want to customize it in your way make a `page-about-us.php`.